# In Coq, "if then else" allows non-boolean first argument?

Tags: if-statement, types, coq

I read in a few tutorials that `if a then b else c` stands for `match a with true => b | false => c end`.  However the former very strangely does not check the type of `a`, while the latter of course makes sure that `a` is a boolean.  For instance,

```
Coq < Check if nil then 1 else 2.
if nil then 1 else 2
     : nat
where
?A : [ |- Type] 


Coq < Check match nil with true => 1 | false => 2 end.
Toplevel input, characters 33-38:
> Check match nil with true => 1 | false => 2 end.
>                                  ^^^^^
Error: Found a constructor of inductive type bool while
a constructor of list is expected.
```

Why is `if ... then ... else ...` allowing its first argument to be anything else than a non-boolean?  Is there some overloading going on?  (`Locate "if".` gives no result.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me quote the [Coq Reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/gallina-extensions.html#if-then-else):

> For inductive types with exactly two constructors and for pattern-matchings expressions which do not depend on the arguments of the constructors, it is possible to use a `if ... then ... else ...` notation. More generally, for an inductive type with constructors `C1` and `C2`, we have the following equivalence:
>
> ```
> if term [dep_ret_type] then term1 else term2
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> match term [dep_ret_type] with
> | C1 _ ... _ => term1              (* we cannot bind the arguments *)
> | C2 _ ... _ => term2
> end
> ```

As you can see, the first constructor is treated as `true` value. Here is an example:

```
Definition is_empty {A : Type} (xs : list A) : bool :=
  if xs then true else false.
```