# Less then function

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I am passing through coq course ["Logical Foundations"](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/lf-current/Basics.html#lab17). Solving problem:

Having less or equal function:

```
Fixpoint leb (n m : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O => true
  | S n' =>
      match m with
      | O => false
      | S m' => leb n' m'
      end
  end.
```

create "less then" function:

```
Definition blt_nat (n m : nat) : bool
  (* REPLACE THIS LINE WITH ":= _your_definition_ ." *). Admitted.
```

As far as I understand it should work like this:

```
if (n == m)
   return false
else
    return (leb n m)
```

I created this:

```
Definition blt_nat (n m : nat) : bool
  match n with
  | m => false
  | _ => leb n m
  end.
```

But it doesn't work - outputs: "Error: This clause is redundant." for the line:

```
| _ => leb n m
```

Please, help.

Comment: I'm not experienced with `coq` but I suspect the first case `| m => ...` doesn't match on `m`, but matches on any value and calls that value `m` (overriding the original `m`). This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46384468/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `match ... with...end`, we can just check the constructors of a particular datatype and find out how it is built based on its constructors. So you cannot do matching a datatype of nat with another datatype of nat. You can find other examples in [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/extended-pattern-matching.html).

```
Definition blt_nat (n m : nat) : bool :=
  match m with
  | 0 => false
  | S m' => leb n m'
  end.
```